# R: Logical Conditions Not Being Respected

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language. I am trying to build a loop that performs the following :

- Step 1: Keep generating two random numbers "a" and "b" until both "a" and "b" are greater than 12
- Step 2: Track how many random numbers had to be generated until it took for Step 1 to be completed
- Step 3: Repeat Step 1 and Step 2 100 times

Since I do not know how to keep generating random numbers until a condition is met, I tried to generate a large amount of random numbers hoping that the condition is met (there is probably a better way to write this):

```
results <- list()


for (i in 1:100){
  
  # do until break
  repeat {
    
    # repeat many random numbers
    a = rnorm(10000,10,1)
    b = rnorm(10000,10,1)
    
    # does any pair meet the requirement
    if (any(a > 12 & b > 12)) {
      
      # put it in a data.frame
      d_i = data.frame(a,b)
      
      # end repeat
      break
    }
  }
  
  # select all rows until the first time the requirement is met
  # it must be met, otherwise the loop would not have ended
  d_i <- d_i[1:which(d_i$a > 10 & d_i$b > 10)[1], ]
  
  # prep other variables and only keep last row (i.e. the row where the condition was met)
  d_i$index = seq_len(nrow(d_i))
  d_i$iteration = as.factor(i)
e_i = d_i[nrow(d_i),]
  
  results[[i]] <- e_i
  
}

results_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)
```

**Problem:** When I look at the results, I noticed that the loop is incorrectly considering the condition to be met, for example:

```
head(results_df)

          a        b index iteration
4  10.29053 10.56263     4         1
5  10.95308 10.32236     5         2
3  10.74808 10.50135     3         3
13 11.87705 10.75067    13         4
1  10.17850 10.58678     1         5
14 10.14741 11.07238     1         6
```

For instance, in each one of these rows - both "a" and "b" are smaller than 12.

Does anyone know why this is happening and can someone please show me how to fix this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why your first condition is `>12`, but on your second condition, you test `>10`?

Comment: @ Colombo: Thank you for your reply! I think you might have identified the mistake in my question! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this way? As you tag `while-loop`, I tried using it.

```
res <- matrix(0, nrow = 0, ncol = 3)    

for (j in 1:100){
  a <- rnorm(1, 10, 1)
  b <- rnorm(1, 10, 1)
  i <- 1
  while(a < 12 | b < 12) {
    a <- rnorm(1, 10, 1)
    b <- rnorm(1, 10, 1)
    i <- i + 1
  }
  x <- c(a,b,i)
  res <- rbind(res, x)
}

head(res)
      [,1]     [,2] [,3]
x 12.14232 12.08977  399
x 12.27158 12.01319 1695
x 12.57345 12.42135  302
x 12.07494 12.64841  600
x 12.03210 12.07949   82
x 12.34006 12.00365  782

dim(res)
[1] 100   3
```