# Error in while (e_i$X1 < 12 | e_i$X2 < 12) { : argument is of length zero

Tags: r, loops, simulation, data-manipulation

In an earlier question ([R: Logical Conditions Not Being Respected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70090177/r-logical-conditions-not-being-respected)), I learned how to make the following simulation :

**Step 1:** Keep generating two random numbers "a" and "b" until both "a" and "b" are greater than 12

**Step 2:** Track how many random numbers had to be generated until it took for Step 1 to be completed

**Step 3:** Repeat Step 1 and Step 2 100 times

```
res <- matrix(0, nrow = 0, ncol = 3)    

for (j in 1:100){
  a <- rnorm(1, 10, 1)
  b <- rnorm(1, 10, 1)
  i <- 1
  while(a < 12 | b < 12) {
    a <- rnorm(1, 10, 1)
    b <- rnorm(1, 10, 1)
    i <- i + 1
  }
  x <- c(a,b,i)
  res <- rbind(res, x)
}

head(res)
      [,1]     [,2] [,3]
x 12.14232 12.08977  399
x 12.27158 12.01319 1695
x 12.57345 12.42135  302
x 12.07494 12.64841  600
x 12.03210 12.07949   82
x 12.34006 12.00365  782
```

**Question:** Now, I am trying to make a slight modification to the above code - Instead of "a" and "b" being produced separately, I want them to be produced "together" (in math terms: "a" and "b" were being produced from two independent univariate normal distributions, now I want them to come from a bivariate normal distribution).

I tried to modify this code myself:

```
library(MASS)

Sigma = matrix(
    c(1,0.5, 0.5, 1), # the data elements
    nrow=2,              # number of rows
    ncol=2,              # number of columns
    byrow = TRUE)        # fill matrix by rows

res <- matrix(0, nrow = 0, ncol = 3)    

for (j in 1:100){
    e_i = data.frame(mvrnorm(n = 1, c(10,10), Sigma))
    e_i$i <- 1
    while(e_i$X1 < 12 | e_i$X2 < 12) {
        e_i = data.frame(mvrnorm(n = 1, c(10,10), Sigma))
        e_i$i <- i + 1
    }
    x <- c(e_i$X1, e_i$X2  ,i)
    res <- rbind(res, x)
}

res = data.frame(res)
```

But this is producing the following error:

> Error in while (e_i$X1 < 12 | e_i$X2 < 12) { : argument is of length
> zero

Comment: @stats555 I've just updated the answer to fix your existing code - there are a couple of issues you need to deal with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly you are trying to see how many samples occur before both values are >=12 and doing that for 100 trials? This is the approach I would take:

```
library(MASS)

for(i in 1:100){
  n <- 1
  while(any((x <- mvrnorm(1, mu=c(10,10), Sigma=diag(0.5, nrow=2)+0.5))<12)) n <- n+1
  if(i==1) res <-            data.frame("a"=x[1], "b"=x[2], n)
  else     res <- rbind(res, data.frame("a"=x[1], "b"=x[2], n))
}
```

Here I am assigning the results of a mvrnorm to `x` within the `while()` call. In that same call, it evaluates whether either are less than 12 using the `any()` function. If that evaluates to `FALSE`, `n` (the counter) is increased and the process repeated. Once `TRUE`, the values are appended to your data.frame and it goes back to the start of the for-loop.

---

Regarding your code, the `mvrnorm()` function is returning a vector, not a matrix, when `n=1` so both values go into a single variable in the data.frame:

```
data.frame(mvrnorm(n = 1, c(10,10), Sigma))
```

Returns:

```
  mvrnorm.n...1..c.10..10...Sigma.
1                         9.148089
2                        10.605546
```

The `matrix()` function within your `data.frame()` calls, along with some tweaks to your use of `i`, will fix your code:

```
library(MASS)

Sigma = matrix(
  c(1,0.5, 0.5, 1), # the data elements
  nrow=2,              # number of rows
  ncol=2,              # number of columns
  byrow = TRUE)        # fill matrix by rows

res <- matrix(0, nrow = 0, ncol = 3)    

for (j in 1:10){
  e_i = data.frame(matrix(mvrnorm(n = 1, c(10,10), Sigma), ncol=2))
  i <- 1
  while(e_i$X1[1] < 12 | e_i$X2[1] < 12) {
    e_i = data.frame(matrix(mvrnorm(n = 1, c(10,10), Sigma), ncol=2))
    i <- i + 1
  }
  x <- c(e_i$X1, e_i$X2  ,i)
  res <- rbind(res, x)
}

res = data.frame(res)
```

Comment: @ rg255 : thank you so much for your answer! I had also noticed this problem " mvrnorm.n...1..c.10..10...Sigma." when I examined the output of the simulation - I was confused as to why the output has 2 rows and 1 column, instead of 1 row and 2 columns. In the future, I will remember to store the results of the simulation into a matrix instead!